# LINQ with Sub Query, Group By, and Having

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, subquery, having

Ok,

I haven't spent much time with LINQ and I'm trying to write a query in C# to replace a select statement with a sub-query, group by and having.  Here is the original query:

```
SELECT * FROM "Users" u1
WHERE u1.Name IN (
    SELECT u2.Name
    From "Users" u2
    WHERE Deleted IS NULL
    Group By u2.Name
    Having Count(UserName) > 1)     
ORDER BY "Name"
```

I can get the sub-query written like this:

```
            var query = 
                from u2 in db.Users
                group u2 by u2.Name into u2g
                where u2g.Count() > 1
                select u2g.Key;
```

But I'm struggling to make that the sub-query and get the complete list of users with duplicate names.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

dbl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group itself contains the users with duplicate names - you're selecting the wrong thing.

```
var dupeUsers = from user in users
                group user by user.Name into dupeNames
                where dupeNames.Count() > 1
                from userDupe in dupeNames
                orderby userDupe.Name
                select userDupe;
```

or, in method syntax

```
var dupeUsers = users.GroupBy(user => user.Name)
                     .Where(dupeNames => dupeNames.Count() > 1)
                     .SelectMany(user => user)
                     .OrderBy(user => user.Name);
```

Comment: I knew what I had wasn't complete, just starting from the sub query in my SQL query and working out. As I said haven't done much LINQ and just haven't figured out how to "think" that way. Thanks for the help. Do you have a good suggestion on a book, website or tutorial for learning LINQ?

Comment: Nothing springs to mind, pretty much any decent C# book will include LINQ examples (C# In Depth by @JonSkeet is excellent in general). I *do* find that it's often more helpful, at least for me, to use the method syntax rather than the query syntax, but this may just be personal preference coming to bear. Something else to note is LINQPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) is an *invaluable* tool for writing LINQ without resorting to F5 testing constantly.